# Как автоматизировать перебор элементов массива?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

*Книга Аарона Хиллегаса "Objective-C. Программирование".
Упражнение в конце Главы 17 "Наш первый класс".*

Проблема: не могу понять, как в итоговом выводе `NSLog` сделать автоматизацию получения элементов массива. Т.е в данном примере убрать `DHL`. и вызывать методы  того объекта, который сейчас в переборе массива.

`StockHolding.h` и `StockHolding.m` оформлены правильно.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        StockHolding *DHL = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [DHL setPurchaseSharePrice:345.67];
        [DHL setNumberOfShares:23];
        [DHL setCurrentSharePrice:389.23];

        StockHolding *Sony = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [Sony setPurchaseSharePrice:587.12];
        [Sony setNumberOfShares:14];
        [Sony setCurrentSharePrice:603.81];

        StockHolding *EPAM = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [EPAM setPurchaseSharePrice:178.45];
        [EPAM setNumberOfShares:35];
        [EPAM setCurrentSharePrice:190.64];

        NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, nil];

        for (NSObject *n in result) {
        NSLog(@"Purchase for: %f\nNumber of shares: %d\nCurrent share price: %f\nCost,$: %f\nValue,$: %f\n", DHL.purchaseSharePrice, DHL.numberOfShares, DHL.currentSharePrice, DHL.costInDollars, DHL.valueInDollars);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (StockHolding *object in objects) {
/* тут уже работаем в объектом object */
}
```

если нужен еще и индекс, тогда подойдет:

```
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(StockHolding *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    /* тоже самое - объект obj, текущий индекс элемента - idx, к тому же тут есть экстренный stop, более изящное решение и замена break, вот пример использования:
    *stop = (object.numberOfShares == 3); */
}];
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Проблема уже решена http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230063/how-can-i-access-the-properties-of-objects-inside-an-nsmutablearray
Очень полезен совет про *stop.